# jquery to construct a string and pass it as a post argument for file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this js code:

```
$("#startSearch").live("click", function(event) {
    $("input:checkbox[name='searchId']:checked").each(function() {
        var searchId = $(this).val();
        var host = '';
        $.post("php/autosearch-get-host.php",{sId: searchId},function(data){
            host = 'http://' + data + '/index.php';
        });
        //alert(host);
        $.getJSON(host,{searchId: $(this).val()},function(){
            pagination("php/pagination.php", $('#currentPage').val(), $('#sortBy').val(), $("#sortMode").val(), "autosearch");
        });
    });
});
```

The php file `php/autosearch-get-host.php` returns a string with the host name. What I want is to get the host from the database, create the URL using string concatenation and pass it as an argument to another `$.post`. `$.post` should use that URL like this:

```
$.getJSON(host,{searchId: $(this).val()},function() {
    pagination("php/pagination.php", $('#currentPage').val(), $('#sortBy').val(), $("#sortMode").val(), "autosearch");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving that one request inside the callback function. As ajax request are asynchronous the variable `host` will be still set to `''` when `$.getJSON` is called

```
$("#startSearch").live("click", function(event) {
    $("input:checkbox[name='searchId']:checked").each(function() {
        var searchId = $(this).val();
        var host = '';
        $.post("php/autosearch-get-host.php",{sId: searchId},function(data){
            host = 'http://' + data + '/index.php';
            $.getJSON(host,{searchId: $(this).val()},function(){
                pagination("php/pagination.php", $('#currentPage').val(), $('#sortBy').val(),  $("#sortMode").val(), "autosearch");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#startSearch").live("click", function(event){
  $("input:checkbox[name='searchId']:checked").each(function(){
    var searchId = $(this).val();
    var host = '';
    $.post("php/autosearch-get-host.php",{sId: searchId},function(data){
      // this code is executed when the POST is finished
      host = 'http://' + data + '/index.php';
      $.getJSON(host,{searchId: $(this).val()},function(){
        pagination("php/pagination.php", $('#currentPage').val(), $('#sortBy').val(), $("#sortMode").val(), "autosearch");
      });
    });
  });
});
```